# ¿Cómo elegir entre un ListView y un TextView?

Tags: java, android

Tengo la típica clase que extiende de `AsynTask` y que se conecta a un servidor para traer los datos y meterlos en mi `ListView` que esta en el layout principal. En dicho layout hay un `TextView` que muestra un texto, un `ImageView` que muestra, a continuación, una imagen y un `ListView`, todo ello dentro de un `RelativeLayout`.

Lo que quiero hacer es: si en el `onPostExecute` mi lista de objetos con la información está con datos, muestro mi `ListView` invocando al adapter, si la lista de objetos con la información está vacía quiero sustituir ese `ListView` por un simple `TextView` indicando que no hay elementos para mostrar.

¿Cómo podría implementar esto?

Comment: Una forma podría ser, en tu XML pon ambos widgets con `visibility=GONE`, en tu clase java valida si tu lista de objetos tiene elementos `lista.size() > 0` a partir de ello entonces decide a quien vas a poner visible `View.VISIBLE`, ¿algo así?

Answer (score 1):

Pueden ser varias soluciones, por ejemplo una puede ser cambiando la visibilidad de los elementos, si suponemos tener el TextView y el ListView dentro de nuestro layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dentro de `onPostExecute()` realizariamos la validación:

```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

         TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
         ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);

        if(datos.isEmpty()){  //NO existen datos.    
          TextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          textView.setText("no hay elementos para mostrar.");
          //ListView se elimina.
          listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }else{
           TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //ListView se muestra cuando tenemos datos!.
          listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }
    }
```

Procurando que cuando el `listView` no es visible no se debe inicializar el adapter ya que no es necesario.

Otra opción sería hacer invisible el `ListView` y agregar la vista del `TextView` programaticamente:

```
  ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
 if(datos.isEmpty()){  //NO existen datos.  
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info);
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("no hay elementos para mostrar.");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
        listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, lo que deberías hacer puede ser lo siguiente:

En tu `layout` define ambos componentes con visibilidad `gone`, para que no se vean por default.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.up.proteccion.ena.Prueba" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Luego, en tu `Activity class` y como bien dices; en el `onPostExcecute` valida el contenido de tu lista

```
    //referecia a los widgets
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    //inicializa tu lista
    List list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    //algún request debe (o no) cargar tu lista
    list = makeRequest("some url");

    //determina la cantidad de items en la lista, luego del request
    if(list.size() > 0) {
        //si es mayor que 0, entonces puedes mostrar tu ListView y cargarlo
        listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //rutinas para cargar el adapter del ListView
    } else {
        //si no es mayor que 0, entonces no hay resultados, haz visible tu TextView
        textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textview.setText("Este es mi mensaje");
    }
```

Si hay algo más que necesites hacer, me dejas saber; pero de esa manera puedes resolver tu problema.